# How to solve conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, bucket

I am trying to copy an s3 bucket from one account to another account. In order to do so, I am following the steps as [described by aws](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/). In step 4, the following policy is suggested:

```
{
 "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
          "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::destination-DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
            "arn:aws:s3:::destination-DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
          ],
          "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
              "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
            }
          },
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:user/Jane"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

However, when I try to do this (after replacing the example buckets and arn), I get the following error: Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement.

How can I solve this error and make sure I can copy the s3 from one account to another?

Comment: Just to make your job simple [Configuring replication when the source and destination buckets are owned by different accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-walkthrough-2.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I need to make a copy of an existing bucket though, with lots of data already stored in it. Also, the destination and source bucket are in the same region.

Answer (score 1):

The condition key you are using is not applicable to the actions you have specified.

[PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html)

[PubObjectAcl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObjectAcl.html)

[ListBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html)

You can checkout here [Condition keys for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys) for various conditions being supported by S3.